# how to skip blank lines while writing to csv file with Spring Batch FlatFileItemWriter

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am trying to write the java data objects to .csv file using the Spring Batch FlatFifileItemWriter exactly as mentioned in the example at below location. http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-example-xml-file-to-csv-file/

The writer configuration is like below.

```
<bean id="cvsFileItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <!-- write to this csv file -->
    <property name="resource" value="file:cvs/report.csv" />
    <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />

    <property name="lineAggregator">
      <bean
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
        <property name="delimiter" value="," />
        <property name="fieldExtractor">
          <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
            <property name="names" value="refId, name, age, csvDob, income" />
           </bean>
        </property>
       </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Since the FlatFileItemWriter has following write() method definition in the API, even though the LineAggregator returns empty String,it still writes to file.

```
StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();
        int lineCount = 0;
        for (T item : items) {
            lines.append(lineAggregator.aggregate(item) + lineSeparator);
            lineCount++;
        }
        try {
            state.write(lines.toString());
        }
```

is there any way to configure it to skip if the line is blank while writing to csv file in java using spring batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add an `ItemProcessor<YourObject>` to your step. In it, you can add a simple `YourObject process(YourObject item)` method that checks if the object will result in a blank line. If not, return the object. If so, return `null`.

This will prevent the items you wish to discard from getting to the writer and will increase the `FILTER_COUNT` when you look at the `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION` table for that Step.

More on [filtering objects](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#filiteringRecords) can be found in the Spring Batch docs.

**Edit:** The tutorial [you referenced](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-example-xml-file-to-csv-file/) in your answer includes an example of a filtering processor (`FilterReportProcessor`) as well.

Comment: Thanks @Dean Clark, For some reason, we are not using processor, is there any other way for example RecursiveCollectionLineAggregator? More over its list of list of object we are passing to writer.

Comment: I strongly recommend you start using a processor. That is the correct design pattern and is the way the Spring Batch framework was meant to be used. Anything else would be a bit of a hack.

Comment: Ok, that make sense. will do that. Appreciated your help

Comment: Happy to help, and best of luck. If you could, just mark the answer as Accepted. Thanks!

Comment: we have catch here. we get items as write(List <MainClass>) where MainClass has the member List<MemberClass>. so we are using CompositeItemWriter which comprises of MainItemWriter, and MemberItemWriter but both will take List<MainClass> as agruments. Hence in Member aggregator we have to get Member as mainClass.getMemberList().getMember(), if member is null or empty it still adds empty line to the ouput file. This I can't do it in processor. is there way to handle this situtation?

Comment: I'd wrap the composite writer in a `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`. If the `memberList` is empty, only pass it to Writer #1. If the list is not empty, pass it to the composite writer so it will hit both Writer #1 and Writer #2

Answer (score 0):

if memberclass is empty here's another way to writer using composite writer.
Create another writer as below.

```
public class YourMemberFileItemWriter extends FlatFileItemWriter<YourMainClass>{
    @Override
    public String doWrite(List<? extends YourMainClass> items) {
        StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();
        for (YourMainClass item : items) {
            if ( YourMainClass.getYourMemberClass() != null) {
                lines.append(this.lineAggregator.aggregate(item)).append(this.lineSeparator);
            }
        }
        return lines.toString();
    }
}
```

Define your composite writer.
CompositeItemWriter compositeItemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(Arrays.asList( mainClassCsv()
,memberClassCsv());
return compositeItemWriter;

Add member class methods as below to composite writer:

```
public FlatFileItemWriter memberClassCsv() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    YourMemberFileItemWriter fileWriter = new YourMemberFileItemWriter();
    fileWriter.setName("yourMemberClass");
    fileWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource("memberfile.csv"));
    fileWriter.setLineAggregator(getMemberClassDelimitedLineAggregator());
    return fileWriter;
}

public DelimitedLineAggregator<YourMainClass> getMemberClassDelimitedLineAggregator() {
    BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<YourMainClass> beanWrapperFieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<YourMainClass>();
    beanWrapperFieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] {
            "memberClassField.fieldname1"
            ,"memberClassField.fieldname2"
            });
    DelimitedLineAggregator<YourMainClass> delimitedLineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<YourMainClass>();
    delimitedLineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");
    delimitedLineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(beanWrapperFieldExtractor);
    return delimitedLineAggregator; 
}
```